# NetUserGetLocalGroups (NULL, ... ) returns 1722 RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE

Tags: windows, winapi

NetUserGetLocalGroups API retrieves a list of local groups to which a specified user belongs:

```
NET_API_STATUS NET_API_FUNCTION NetUserGetLocalGroups(
  LPCWSTR servername,
  LPCWSTR username,
  DWORD   level,
  DWORD   flags,
  LPBYTE  *bufptr,
  DWORD   prefmaxlen,
  LPDWORD entriesread,
  LPDWORD totalentries
);
```

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netusergetlocalgroups

If *servername* parameter is NULL, the function executes for the local computer. This works fine in our test environment, and it fails with error 1722 (RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE) for one of our customers.

Microsoft documents this as: "This error is returned if the *servername* parameter could not be found."

At first sight, this doesn't make sense because NULL is an acceptable value.

What should I check on the customer's machine to figure out why this fails? How to mitigate this issue?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing how you are using `NetUserGetLocalGroups()`

Comment: Maybe you can refer to : [Troubleshoot Remote Procedure Call (RPC) errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/troubleshoot-tcpip-rpc-errors)

Comment: @RemyLebeau He could do that; but you realize you'd have to run it on one of his customer's PCs.

Comment: I tested it on a non-domain-joined machine; and it works fine. So that's not it. :(